# How do you disable an ACF button while waiting for the result of an AJAX request?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

If you create an [ACF button](https://www.acf-extended.com/features/fields/button) and enable the `Ajax call - Trigger ajax event on click` setting, how do you disable the button during the AJAX request so that multiple requests are not accidentally submitted at once?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will disable (ghost out) the button once it's pressed, and re-enable it once the AJAX request is complete.

Change `my_button_name` to the field name of your button. Also, ensure that the `my_acf_admin_enqueue_scripts` and `my_acf_admin_print_scripts` function names are unique.

For more information refer to the [ACF Javascript API](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/javascript-api/) and the [ACF Button Field](https://www.acf-extended.com/features/fields/button).

```php
add_action('acf/input/admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_acf_admin_enqueue_scripts');

function my_acf_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
    add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_acf_admin_print_scripts');
    function my_acf_admin_print_scripts() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
            acf.addAction('acfe/fields/button/before/name=my_button_name', function($el, data){
              var field = acf.getField(data.field_key);
              field.disable();
            });
            
            acf.addAction('acfe/fields/button/success/name=my_button_name', function(response, $el, data) {
              var field = acf.getField(data.field_key);
              field.enable();
            });
        });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```